# Multiple Stacked Graph with three dimensions

Tags: r, charts, excel-2007

I have a dataset that I need to represent visually. It has three axes - State (X), Tons (Y), and Year (Z). The Tons are split into Imports, Exports, and Internal. In Excel I am able to show the data along all three axes but have to create separate graphs for Imports, Exports, and Internal. What I want to show is the Imports, Exports and Internal stacked together along along the three dimensions.

I am sharing a .pdf which shows the dataset, the separate graphs by Imports, Exports, and Internal and my desired output. Link to the PDF: http://bit.ly/nvgv4j

I want to avoid creating it outside a graphing/data program as I want to have flexibility to change the graph as the data changes. R or Excel works for me.

*Sample data indirectly from OP*:

```
Type State 2007 2020 2040  
E Alabama 96976 119425 153018  
E California 159615 229495 504810  
E Florida 80478 101040 143784  
E Georgia 128221 141193 183145
E Texas 344165 421491 559856  
I Alabama 129223 145461 202160   
I California 227403 275670 331032  
I Florida 166390 162251 200458  
I Georgia 205480 225247 310748  
I Texas 451072 505401 688487  
N Alabama 275979 314230 384861  
N California 1257797 1474378 2181214  
N Florida 716259 713979 909170  
N Georgia 407336 404705 488339  
N Texas 1690048 1995219 2620223
```

Comment: Use facetted plots instead, either with `lattice` or `ggplot2`

Comment: Agree with Andrie as far as the R tag goes. Use Excel for that purpose. The charting gurus in R are not trying to emulate the distorted presentations that Excel creates.

Comment: I bet you would get more help if you put the data from that pdf into something we could import into R. Then it would be easy to show you what some options are.

Comment: @krishnan Is not recomended but you can use highcharter http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html#hc_chart